# Why is undefined being set instead of the value after ||?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and logs:

```
console.log('PROCESS:', process.env.BACKEND_URL)
api.serverUrl = process.env.BACKEND_URL || url[env].backend
console.log('URL:', url[env].backend)
console.log('API:', api.serverUrl)
```

`process.env.BACKEND_URL` is `undefined` so I `expected api.serverUrl` to be set to `url[env].backend`.

However the logs show this:

```
PROCESS: undefined
URL: https://vrbackendus.avosapps.us/api
API: undefined
```

Why is this? Why isn't `expected api.serverUrl` being set to `url[env].backend`?

Comment: Are you sure that it's actually `undefined`, not the string `"undefined"`? They both print out the same with `console.log` (just a color tweak in my browser console). Perhaps check that `process.env.BACKEND_URL === undefined` is `true`?

Comment: The only possibility here is `process.env.BACKEND_URL` is `'undefined'` instead of `undefined`. Otherwise this won't happen.

Comment: double check your spelling in the actual code, seems ok here

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right. How can I turn `'undefined'` into `undefined`?

Comment: `x = x === 'undefined' ? undefined : x;` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine. The problem must be with the values in the variables.

```js
/*Values i had given to test*/
var process ={};
process.env={};
var api={};
process.env.BACKEND_URL = "undefined";
var url = [];
var env = "test";
url[env] ={};
url[env].backend = "test";
/*****/

console.log('PROCESS:', process.env.BACKEND_URL)
api.serverUrl = (process.env.BACKEND_URL === "undefined" ? url[env].backend : process.env.BACKEND_URL); 
console.log('URL:', url[env].backend)
console.log('API:', api.serverUrl)
```

Updated the code in response to your comment, it is `"undefined"` instead of `undefined`

Comment: I think the problem is that `undefined` is actually `'undefined'`. How can I turn `'undefined'` into `undefined`.

Comment: @HarikrishnanN: You'd need to switch to ternary check, or you'll never store the non-undefined value of `BACKEND_URL`. Something like `api.serverUrl = process.env.BACKEND_URL !== "undefined" ? process.env.BACKEND_URL : url[env].backend`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. Did not think of that... :) Updated with the change